# Error in Install cartalyst/tags on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i want to install [cartalyst/tags](https://github.com/cartalyst/tags/tree/master) on laravel 5.4 but i got some errors after `composer install` / `composer update`.

Here the errors:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
    - Installation request for cartalyst/tags ^3.0 -> satisfiable by cartalyst/tags[v3.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
    - cartalyst/tags v3.0.0 requires illuminate/database 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0|don't install illuminate/database v5.3.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0|don't install illuminate/database v5.3.16
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0|don't install illuminate/database v5.3.23
    - don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0|don't install illuminate/database v5.3.4
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5].
```

Answer (score 1):

[FIXED] package `cartalyst/tags` can use `dev-master` instead `3.0.*` in `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue with **laravel 5.4** and used package may not supportive. Could you please try with `Laravel 5.3`:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel test "5.3.*"
```

Hope this work for you!